# ASP.NET MVC 3 Remote Validation from Ajax Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the remote validation attribute in MVC 3 to check the uniqueness of the email address, and I can't get it to fire when using an ajax form. I have a form _SignupForm that I use in two scenarios: 1. As a jquery dialog when javascript is enabled, and 2. As a normal page when javascript is disabled (also available by browsing to the page).

When I navigate to the normal cshtml page, all of the validation works as expected. When I use the form in the jquery dialog, all of the validation works with the exception of the remote validation.

Here is my model:

```
public class SignUpModel : BaseModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Your Name")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
    [Remote("EmailAddress", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Account already exists", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    [Display(Name = "Your Email")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Choose a password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Retype password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Your passwords do not match")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Receive a weekly newsletter")]
    public bool ReceiveNewsletter { get; set; }


    public bool Agree { get; set; }
```

Here is my form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "signupDialog" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <ol>
        @*name*@
        <li>
            <div class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </div>
        </li>
        @*email*@
        <li>
            <div class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
            </div>
        </li>
        @*password*@
        <li>
            <div class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
        </li>
        @*confirm password*@
        <li>
            <div class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
        </li>
        @*newsletter*@
        <li>
            <div class="field">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ReceiveNewsletter)
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReceiveNewsletter)
            </div>
        </li>
        @*terms*@
        <li>
            <div class="field">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Agree)
            </div>
            <div class="label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Agree)
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />        
        </li>
</ol>
}
```

When I inspect the field using firebug, this is what I see in both cases:

```
<input id="EmailAddress" type="text" value="" name="EmailAddress" data-val-required="Please enter your email address" data-val-remote-url="/garden/Validation/EmailAddress" data-val-remote-type="POST" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.EmailAddress,*.UserId" data-val-remote="Account already exists" data-val="true">
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit**
After a little more digging, it appears that the client side validation is not working at all in my jquery dialog. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem with remote validation in MVC3. In my case, I'm dynamically loading a form inside of a JQuery.dialog() using a JQuery.load() method.

I can get Client validation working, as long as I have the flags for unobstrusive and clientvalidation set along with respective js files, by calling the following after the form is loaded:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));
```

Then, before making my $.ajax call to post the results, I check to see if the form is valid:

```
if ($(form).valid()) {
```

This causes the client side to fire and gives me client side validation. However, when that happens it also fires the MVC remote validation code but with empty values, causing the remote validation methods to fail as there is nothing to compare.